# My question has nothing to do with the speed of processing sorted/unsorted arrays

Tags: discussion, bug, related-questions

Does the algorithm that finds "Related" questions need a tweak, to reduce the score given to highly upvoted questions?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30372211/3933089) has really nothing to do with why processing a sorted array is faster than processing an unsorted array. The only connections, as far as I can see, are the Java tag, and the (unused) `String[] args` array in the `main` method. And yet it's the third hit in the "Related" list.

But this isn't really an issue about that one question. Pretty much everything I look at seems to be deemed closely related to the performance of sorted/unsorted arrays.

This, of course, has a positive feedback loop that makes the problem worse: that question appears all over the place, and it's so highly upvoted that everyone looks at it to see what it's about, and then upvotes... so its relatedness score tomorrow will be even higher than it is today...

Comment: It is a first step to know these results are wrong. But maybe more importantly, which question(s) are a better *related* target? Based on that it is easier to see if a tweaked algorithm does better....

Comment: I believe I have read similar post regarding "unrelated 'related' post" somewhere on MSO, but I couldn't find it currently.

Comment: @rene Sure. But it seems fairly clear that things get deemed "related" at least partly on the basis of being good questions, and that the weight given to this is too high. So my proposal is just to back this off a bit.

Comment: @AndrewT. on MSE is the exact duplicate [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223880/unrelated-popular-content-constantly-in-related-links)